# Safe implementation of script tag hack to do XSS?

Tags: security, cross-domain, xss, jsonp, same-origin-policy

Like a lot of developers, I want to make JavaScript served up by Server "A" talk to a web service on Server "B" but am stymied by the current incarnation of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). The most secure means of overcoming this (that I can find) is a server script that sits on Server "A" and acts as a proxy between it and "B". But if I want to deploy this JavaScript in a variety of customer environments (RoR, PHP, Python, .NET, etc. etc.) and can't write proxy scripts for all of them, what do I do?

Use JSONP, [some people say](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/). Well, Doug Crockford pointed out [on his website](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html) and [in interviews](http://thechangelog.com/post/676820023/episode-0-2-6-douglas-crockford-on-json-and-javascript-f) that the script tag hack (used by JSONP) is an unsafe way to get around the same origin policy. There's no way for the script being served by "A" to verify that "B" is who they say they are and that the data it returns isn't malicious or will capture sensitive user data on that page (e.g. credit card numbers) and transmit it to dastardly people. That seems like a reasonable concern, but what if I just use the script tag hack by itself and communicate strictly in JSON? Is that safe? If not, why not? Would it be any more safe with HTTPS? Example scenarios would be appreciated.

**Addendum:** Support for IE6 is required. Third-party browser extensions are not an option. Let's stick with addressing the merits and risks of the script tag hack, please.

Comment: What do you mean by `what if I just use the script tag hack by itself and communicate strictly in JSON?` ?

Comment: The script served up by "A" would include a statement that would append a script tag to the client DOM. That script tag would include an AJAX call that would fetch pure JSON data from "B" at a different domain. If the script served up by "A" parses the response as JSON, wouldn't any JavaScript padding (aka JSONP, malicious or otherwise) result in a parse error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies to all who attempted to answer my question. It proceeded under a false assumption about how the script tag hack works. The assumption was that one could simply append a script tag to the DOM and that the **contents** of that appended script tag would not be restricted by the same origin policy.

If I'd bothered to test my assumption before posting the question, I would've known that it's the **source attribute** of the appended tag that's unrestricted. JSONP takes this a step further by establishing a protocol that wraps traditional JSON web service responses in a callback function.

Regardless of how the script tag hack is used, however, there is no way to screen the response for malicious code since browsers execute whatever JavaScript is returned. And neither IE, Firefox nor Webkit browsers check SSL certificates in this scenario. Doug Crockford is, so far as I can tell, correct. There is no safe way to do cross domain scripting as of JavaScript 1.8.5.

Answer (score 2):

Currently browser venders are split on how cross domain javascript should work.  A secure and easy to use optoin is Flash's [Crossdomain.xml file](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html). Most languages have a [Cross Domain Proxies](http://ajaxpatterns.org/archive/Cross-Domain_Proxy.php) written for them,  and they are open source.

A more nefarious solution would be to use xss how the [Sammy Worm](http://namb.la/popular/tech.html) used to spread. XSS can be used to "read" a remote domain using xmlhttprequest.  XSS isn't required if the other domains have added a `<script src="https://YOUR_DOMAIN"></script>`.  A script tag like this allows you to evaluate your own JavaScript in the context of another domain,  which is identical to XSS.

It is also important to note that even with the restrictions on the same origin policy you can  get the browser to transmit requests to any domain,  you just can't read the response.  This is the basis of CSRF.  You could write invisible image tags to the page dynamically to get the browser to fire off an unlimited number of GET requests.  This use of image tags is how an attacker obtains `documnet.cookie` using XSS on another domain.   CSRF POST exploits work by building a form and then calling `.submit()` on the form object.

To understand the Same Orgin Policy, CSRF and XSS better you must read the [Google Browser Security Handbook](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Main).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net), it's a clean javascript library that allows you to communicate across the domain boundary without any server side interaction. It even supports RPC out of the box.
It supports all 'modern' browser, as well as IE6 with transit times < 15ms.

A common usecase is to use it to expose an ajax endpoint, allowing you to do cross-domain ajax with little effort (check out the small sample on the front page).

Answer (score 0):

> What if I just use the script tag hack by itself and communicate strictly in JSON? Is that safe? If not, why not?

Lets say you have two servers - frontend.com and backend.com. frontend.com includes a `<script>` tag like this - `<script src="http://backend.com/code.js"></script>`.

when the browser evaluates `code.js` is considered a part of `frontend.com` and NOT a part of `backend.com`. So, if code.js contained XHR code to communicate with backend.com, *it would fail*.

> Would it be any more safe with HTTPS? Example scenarios would be appreciated.

If you just converted your `<script src="https://backend.com/code.js>` to https, it would **NOT** be any secure. If the rest of your page is http, then an attacker could easily man-in-the-middle the page and change that https to http - or worse, include his own javascript file.

If you convert the entire page and all its components to https, it would be more secure. But if you are paranoid enough to do that, you should also be paranoid NOT to depend on an external server for you data. If an attacker compromises backend.com, he has effectively got enough leverage on frontend.com, frontend2.com and all of your websites.

In short, https is helpful, but it won't help you one bit if your backend server gets compromised.

> So, what are my options?

1. Add a proxy server on each of your client applications. You don't need to write any code, your webserver can automatically do that for you. If you are using Apache, look up mod_rewrite
2. If your users are using the latest browsers, you could consider using [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).
3. As The Rook pointed out, you could also use Flash + Crossdomain. Or you could use Silverlight and its equivalent of Crossdomain. Both technologies allow you to communicate with javascript - so you just need to write a utility function and then normal js code would work. I believe YUI already provides a flash wrapper for this - check [YUI3 IO](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/io/)

> What do you recommend?

My recommendation is to create a proxy server, and use https throughout your website.